# What is this rotation behavior in XNA?

Tags: xna

I am just starting out in XNA and have a question about rotation. When you multiply a vector by a rotation matrix in XNA, it goes counter-clockwise. This I understand.

However, let me give you an example of what I don't get. Let's say I load a random art asset into the pipeline.  I then create some variable to increment every frame by 2 radians when the update method runs(testRot += 0.034906585f). The main thing of my confusion is, the asset rotates clockwise in this screen space. This confuses me as a rotation matrix will rotate a vector counter-clockwise.

One other thing, when I specify where my position vector is, as well as my origin, I understand that I am rotating about the origin. Am I to assume that there are perpendicular axis passing through this asset's origin as well? If so, where does rotation start from? In other words, am I starting rotation from the top of the Y-axis or the x-axis?

Comment: @llya - You should probably accept the answers to your other questions so that others will want to answer your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The XNA SpriteBatch works in **Client Space**. Where "up" is Y-, not Y+ (as in Cartesian space, projection space, and what most people usually select for their world space). This makes the rotation appear as clockwise (not counter-clockwise as it would in Cartesian space). The actual coordinates the rotation is producing are the same.

Rotations are relative, so they don't really "start" from any specified position.

If you are using maths functions like `sin` or `cos` or `atan2`, then absolute *angles* always start from the X+ axis as zero radians, and the positive rotation direction rotates towards Y+.

---

The order of operations of `SpriteBatch` looks something like this:

1. Sprite starts as a quad with the top-left corner at (0,0), its size being the same as its texture size (or `SourceRectangle`).
2. Translate the sprite back by its origin (thus placing its origin at (0,0)).
3. Scale the sprite
4. Rotate the sprite
5. Translate the sprite by its position
6. Apply the matrix from `SpriteBatch.Begin`

This places the sprite in Client Space.

Finally a matrix is applied to each batch to transform that Client Space into the Projection Space used by the GPU. (Projection space is from (-1,-1) at the bottom left of the viewport, to (1,1) in the top right.)

Comment: Wow, thanks man. Explained very well. I searched tutorials/books and all they did was talk about these without going in-depth.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to XNA, allow me to introduce a library that will greatly help you out while you learn. It is called XNA Debug Terminal and is an open source project that allows you to run arbitrary code during runtime. So you can see if your variables have the value you expect. All this happens in a terminal display on top of your game and without pausing your game. It can be downloaded at http://www.protohacks.net/xna_debug_terminal
It is free and very easy to setup so you really have nothing to lose.